# HTML: Image over borders

Tags: html, image, border

I can't figure that out. I have a div with an image that has the same width as the div. Under the picture I want to display some text. So it is basically a box with an image in the first upper half and text in the lower half. Now I want to add a border around the whole div. This resets the position of my image because it has to make room for the border. Is there a way so the image postion does not get affected by the border? So it is basically over the border?

```
<div style="background-color: white; padding-bottom: 60px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px;     margin-right: 20px; border-left: solid 9px #adbb0c; border-right: solid 9px #adbb0c">
<img src="vogelstimmen.png">
<div align="left" style="padding: 20px"><h2>In iTunes kaufen</h2></div>
<p id="extender">
<a href="#" id="extend"><img src="more.png" align="right" style="margin-top: 55px"></a>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with a working image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you adjust the position of the Image using a margin to compensate for the border thickness?

Change the img tag as below.

```
<img src="http://static.bbci.co.uk/frameworks/barlesque/2.70.0/orb/4/img/bbc-blocks-dark.png" style="margin-left:-9px">
```

Comment: If you haven't used JSFiddle before, it is a super cool tool for fiddling with html/css and js. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Of course, I could not because it said "you can accept in 5 minutes"

Comment: Cool no problems, didn't realize that. Sorry